# Open in New Tab - Outsystems Web

Tags: target, outsystems

I have a list displayed inside a web block. I need the system function that when I right click the filename displayed, and select *open in new tab*, the file preview will display on the new tab but when I tried doing it, the new tab goes to the url * about:blank#blocked * . What could possibly be the reason for this and how can i resolve this? Thank you

Comment: what is your url on the link?

Answer (score 0):

**This is should work**, although it is for left click, I am sure an *extended property* call *onRightclick* or something along those lines will work.

```
In the Interface tab right click your UIFlow (For me it is called Common)
    Add External Site
    Rename External Site to "ExternalURL"
    Right click ExternalURL
        Add Input Parameter
        Name the new Input "URL"
            Set Is Manditory as Yes
            Set Data Type as Text
    On your link properties
        Set Destination to UIFlowName\ExternalURL (For me it is called Common\ExternalURL)
            Set URL to your desired address (example: "http://google.com")
            Add an Extended Property called "formtarget"
                Set its value to "_blank"
```